# How to get access token in google oauth in C#(ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am using C#. I successfully got the authorisation code but I don't know how to get the access token. I prefer the [Google website](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer). But, I don't know how to apply it in C#(ASP.net).

Comment: When I follow the link you provided, I get [there](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet) and [there](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows).  
There is also some [documentation from .NET available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the dotnetopenauth library (it is used here at SO) for accessing Google's services. Instead of rolling your own token manager I would suggest using a pre existing one and extending it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive SDK includes a complete ASP.NET MVC sample that you can use as reference:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This.

```
String client_id = "<OAUTH_client_id >";
String client_secret = "<OAUTH_client_secret>";
    
var BaseAddress = "https://adddress.com";
var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress) };
      
var creds = $"client_id={client_id}&client_secret{client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials";
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
var content = new StringContent(creds, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = httpClient.PostAsync("/oauth2/token", content).Result;
var jsonContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    
var tokenObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BearerViewModel>(jsonContent);
var token = tokenObj.access_token;
```